# amsmath breaks LaTeX3 assignments

Tags: amsmath, expl3, latex3

I am trying to use a global boolean variable `b` within a LaTeX3 function. I would like my function to print `F` if `b` is false and toggle it to true, and to print `T` if `b` is true.

This works great in text and regular math, but always prints `T` if I try to use it within `amsmath` environments like `gather` or `align`. It looks like `amsmath` is expanding/evaluating the contents of its environments at least once before the final render. How can I avoid this / fix my function?

Here is a MWE, where I stripped out good practices like `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\cs_new_protected:Npn` to get it as minimal as possible:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defit}{m}{
  \bool_new:c    { g_it_#1_used  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getit}{m}{
  \bool_if:cTF { g_it_#1_used } { T } { F\bool_gset_true:c { g_it_#1_used } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defit{test}\getit{test}\getit{test}\getit{test}

\defit{eqn}
\[
  \getit{eqn} \getit{eqn} \getit{eqn}
\]

\defit{ams}
\begin{gather*}
  \getit{ams} \getit{ams} \getit{ams}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The expected output is `FTT` three times. Instead, I get `FTT`, `FTT`, `TTT`.

Comment: note you will have the same issue with any text that is set twice eg captions, tabularx etc

Comment: Unrelated: not a good idea to use the minimal class, it is only for internal testing. Might be better to use the standard article class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some `amsmath` environments, like `gather` or `align`, do not typeset their contents only once: the do once for measuring (and then discard), and another time for actually typesetting.

Your `\getit` function, however, sets the boolean globally as soon as it's used for the first time (which for the `gather` environment happens while measuring), and the output of the measuring run (which *is* `FTT`) is discarded, and then you only see `TTT` for the typesetting run.

You can use the `\ifmeasuring@` conditional to detect if you are in the measuring run, and in that case skip changing the boolean:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \defit { m }
  { \bool_new:c { g_it_#1_used_bool } }
\NewDocumentCommand \getit { m }
  {
    \bool_if:cTF { g_it_#1_used_bool }
      { T }
      {
        F
        \legacy_if:nF { measuring@ }
          { \bool_gset_true:c { g_it_#1_used_bool } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defit{test}\getit{test}\getit{test}\getit{test}

\defit{eqn}
\[
  \getit{eqn} \getit{eqn} \getit{eqn}
\]

\defit{ams}
\begin{gather*}
  \getit{ams} \getit{ams} \getit{ams}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the output while measuring should be the same width as the output while typesetting, otherwise your output may look misaligned.